# Google Authentication get access token using refresh token

Tags: push-notification, google-calendar-api, google-authentication, google-developers-console

I am using [Push Notifications](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/push) API for integrating client's calendar event. I have created channel also. But I am not able to get refresh token while authentication. I need to get user consent from UI and based on the verification code I am getting access token and refresh token. But when I am trying to get access token using existing refresh token, it is asking for client Id and secret. As I am just using consent from user I do not have client Id and client secret for each user. How can I resolve this for my application?

I am using below code for authentication

```
private static Credential getCredentials(final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT)
      throws IOException {
    // Load client secrets.
    InputStream in = CalendarQuickstart.class.getResourceAsStream(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
    if (in == null) {
      throw new FileNotFoundException("Resource not found: " + CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
    }
    GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets =
        GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

    // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow =
        new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
            .setDataStoreFactory(new FileDataStoreFactory(new java.io.File(TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH)))
            .setAccessType("offline")
            .build();
    LocalServerReceiver receiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(8888).build();
    return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, receiver).authorize("user");
  }
```

Here is how I am calling calender API

```
public static void main(String... args) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    // Build a new authorized API client service.
    final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
    Credential credential = getCredentials(HTTP_TRANSPORT);

    String accessToken = credential.getAccessToken();

    Calendar service =
        new Calendar.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, googleCredential)
            .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
            .build();

    System.out.println(accessToken);

    // List the next 10 events from the primary calendar.
    DateTime now = new DateTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
    Events events =
        service
            .events()
            .list("primary")
            .setMaxResults(10)
            .setTimeMin(now)
            .setOrderBy("startTime")
            .setSingleEvents(true)
            .execute();
    List<Event> items = events.getItems();
    if (items.isEmpty()) {
      System.out.println("No upcoming events found.");
    } else {
      System.out.println("Upcoming events");
      for (Event event : items) {
        DateTime start = event.getStart().getDateTime();
        if (start == null) {
          start = event.getStart().getDate();
        }
        // System.out.printf("%s %s (%s)\n", event.getId(), event.getSummary(), event.toString());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: please edit your question and include your code. without seeing how you are refreshing your token its hard to help you.  The client id and client secret are from google developer console where you created your application and credentials for that application.

Comment: Can you share the full error message as well?

Comment: This code works fine but if I want to use refresh token without client id and client secret, just based on existing auth token, then how can i do that? Basically, i am not able to get the refresh token based on access token as i do not have client id and client secret for next call.